# How can I write a non recursive algorithm to add root to tree?

Tags: algorithm, non-recursive

I need a non recursive algorithm that will add up the root to the tree values, and then display the value that is the highest. Not to add up every element in the tree, just the highest value way to get from root to leaf.

> ```
>                         2
>                      /      \
>                     8         6
> ```

in this example the answer would be 10
must be in O(n) timing

Comment: This smells like homework, have you tried something yet?

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: i dont know where to start

Comment: Try something simpler. You must traverse the tree non-recursively. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: thats what im struggling with

Answer (score 0):

Try it breadth-first. Add the children of the actual node to a list, then proceed along that list until you reach its end.